# read pdf file stored in mobile windows phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7

what i want to do is to read PDF file store on memory card and display is content to the user as Adobe acrobat reader do. 
 DO anyone knows how to read PDF file from memory card in windows phone 7 or convert it to string or else it can it converted to HTML format so that webbrowser control can be use to display its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think the current set of Windows Phone devices do not support external memory cards (microSD, SD) and also there is no way to open Adobe Acrobat on a device from your application.

I would recommend you to create an HTML file or "text file" out of your PDF file. Save it to the isolated storage or as a part of your application and then you will be able to read it within your application and display to user.

Here is a [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx) of displaying HTML in Windows Phone.

Comment: I am using isolatedstorage for storing file,but while reading same file,string is like '%PDF-1.4
%äüöß
2 0 obj
<</Length 3 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>
stream
x��T�j�@����@loIsy`Y���@]0�r��$�B��Gs��mwK ���F���wu' as like we view PDF file using notepad,i just want to display contains as an PDF file,do we have some control in wp7 or how should i convert it into string or HTML so that i can display it using webBrowser...please reply

Comment: I don't think we do have controls that display PDF files (at least, out of a box). I guess, the best option here is to store it already in a HTML if it is possible, not to convert it in a runtime.